# API request does not refresh the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, frontend

Today I wanted to test axios.all, so I made the script that you can see below only there is a small problem. The script allows me to retrieve data from the API when I run it, however there is something I don't understand. The functions setInterval execute an action every 30 seconds as requested but it displays exactly the same values and when I reload the page manually it's the same a new console.log appears but with exactly the same data. My goal is of course that once the first request is done, other requests can be done to update the data, I have the impression that the data is stored in a cache and that it never expires

Thanks for your help

Here is my script :

```js
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [uniData, setUniDataTop] = useState([]);
  const [susData, setSusDataSec] = useState([]);
  const [Ptest, setPtest] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = () => {
    const uniAPI = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/exchanges/uniswap/tickers";
    const susAPI =
      "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/exchanges/sushiswap/tickers";

    const getUniPrice = axios.get(uniAPI);
    const getSusPrice = axios.get(susAPI);
    axios.all([getUniPrice, getSusPrice]).then(
      axios.spread((...allData) => {
        const priceuni = allData[0].data.tickers;
        const pricesus = allData[1].data.tickers;
        console.log(pricesus);
        console.log(priceuni);
        const unitest = priceuni?.find(
          (element) =>
            element.trade_url ===
            "https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap?inputCurrency=ETH&outputCurrency=0xc669928185dbce49d2230cc9b0979be6dc797957"
        );
        const unitest2 = unitest?.converted_last.usd;
        const sustest = pricesus?.find(
          (element) =>
            element.trade_url ===
            "https://app.sushi.com/swap?inputCurrency=0x64aa3364f17a4d01c6f1751fd97c2bd3d7e7f1d5&outputCurrency=0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f"
        );
        const sustest2 = sustest?.converted_last.usd;
        const unitable = [unitest2, "ETH/USDT", "UniSwap"];
        const sustable = [sustest2, "ETH/USDT", "Uniswap"];
        var number = [unitable, sustable];
        number.sort();
        const percentage = [(number[1][0] - number[0][0]) / number[1][0]] * 100;
        setUniDataTop(number[1][0]);
        setSusDataSec(number[0][0]);
        setPtest(percentage);
      })
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  setInterval(fetchData, 30 * 1000);

  return (
    <>
      {uniData}
      <br />
      {susData}
      <br />
      {Ptest}%
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Never use `setInterval` outside of `useEffect` in react. It will create multiple intervals

Comment: ok thanks I corrected it, but do you have any idea why it always shows me the same data?

Answer (score 0):

[@Konrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089567/konrad-linkowski) is correct. You can't call `setInterval` outside of `useEffect`, in your implementation on the first render `setInterval` run the `fetch` which will call the api. Then it will update the state which will in return re-render the page and then the `setInterval` run again and update the state and this will go on until the application crashes due to lack of memory.

Instead, you can put the `setInterval` inside of the `useEffect`. This way the `setInterval` is created once when the component mounts for the first time and is not created again and again when the component re-renders.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setInterval(() => {
      fetchData();
    }, 30 * 1000);

    return () => {
      // clears the interval when the unmounts 
      clearInterval(timeout);
    };
  }, []);


// setInterval(fetchData, 30 * 1000) // remove this
```

And since your data in the state is most likely number or string, you can remove the `[]` from the `useState([])` too.

[image: Data in the view]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the explanation but fetchdata is sending me the same data every 30 seconds instead of fetching new ones, do you have any idea where this comes from?